# Caculating packet offset

Tags: wireshark, icmp, packet

In Wireshark, if I want to write a filter which accepts only ICMP destination unreachable ( type 3 ) messages, the filter is `icmp[0] == 3` .

How do I count the packet offset of 0 in this instance ?

**EDIT**

[image]

Based on the above image from Wikipedia, the ICMP type is under 0-7 bits. Therefore it is the first byte and therefore 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is correct, `icmp[0]` indeed matches the first byte of the ICMP header containing the type. However, I find it hard to read, you should use `icmp.type eq 3` instead. This is also much easier when the field is longer than one byte.

Here is the [display field reference](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/icmp.html) for ICMP.

Comment: He might be trying to write a *capture* filter; [the syntax for them is more limited](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html).

Comment: Agree, didn't even consider that... my bad. I like the new syntax, nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to write a capture filter rather than a display filter; if you're trying to write a display filter, Martin Isaksson is correct, you should do `icmp.type == 3`.

Yes, 0 is the offset within the ICMP packet.

In newer versions of libpcap, [the syntax supports some more convenient ways of writing the filter](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html), namely `icmp[icmptype] == icmp-unreach`.  WinPcap is based on a version of libpcap with that syntax, so [it supports it as well](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__language.html).

It is arguably a bug that Wireshark doesn't let you say something similar, namely

```
icmp.type == "Destination unreachable"
```

in a display filter.  I'll look at fixing that.